# First movie with a "character on a cracking glass floor"-suspense scene

Tags: first-appearance, lost-world-jurassic-park

The other day, I re-watched ["The Lost World: Jurassic Park" (1997)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119567/) and I was amazed by the suspense scene in which Julianne Moore's character finds herself on a glass panel that starts cracking:

I'm sure that I saw similar scenes in later movies (that now I don't recall), and I wonder if Spielberg is the first to come up with this concept.

**Question:** What is the first movie featuring a suspense scene in which a character finds herself/himself on a glass surface that starts cracking a little at a time, putting her/him at risk of a dangerous fall?

Comment: Compulsory TVTropes link - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OminousCrack

Comment: I was about to say, Alias' season finale comes to mind, but have no idea what the first feature film may be...But Ominous Crack may not necessarily include actually falling through glass ceiling/panel, since Alias is not listed there, I feel certain I have seen characters do this elsewhere, but I just can't recall.

Comment: @CGCampbell I would be more curious about why somebody feel the need of close/downvote this question as 'trivia', while there are many very similar questions (just check the column on the right).

Comment: @CGCampbell - We are also allowed to ask about "first appearances"  (see the tag) and while that might seem like trivia, it is an allowed kind of question. So I would agree with marco89_ plenty of these exist and are accepted here. Argumentatively, Q's like this are sometimes about the history of film making and learning where ideas might originate or how they originated. That is apart of this site too!

Comment: As for why a glass ceiling, panel, surface is important at all, it is a device, trope, prop, etc that generates suspense and thus is important aspect of story telling in a visual medium.

Comment: Specifically **glass**? Not ice, or any other material thay may crack and break in a similar fashion?

Comment: @Flater: I don't know what that material was, but I can't think of any transparent materials that would behave in a manner consistent with what was shown unless the space below was filled with liquid or pressurized gas (as would often be the case with e.g. ice).  The tensile strength of non-laminated glass would drop to zero in the presence of cracks, and a laminated glass/plastic sandwich would retain most of its tensile strength even if the glass is totally shattered.